# What is the best DynamoDB architecture for storing several document types?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Reading into Amazon DynamoDB doc I still can't understand what is the best way of using it for the most common task - having several types of documents (for example, 'user', 'event', 'news') all with unique ids.
As I understand, since DynamoDB implies restrictions only on document primary key, we can store in it any data having one. Thus the most natural solution looks like:

```
- partion key 'type' is document type - 'user', 'event' etc
- sort key is uuid
```

But this contradicts to official doc, according to it the better one is:

```
- partition key 'id' is just uuid
- sort key is type - 'user', 'event'
```

But this contradicts with common sense due to key names.
Finally, we can just create 3 different DynamoDB instances for users, events and news, all having uuid as partiton key and no sort key.
Which solution is the best or common practice of DynamoDB usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifics would be required for definitive statements, but making some assumptions about what your data looks like:

```
- partion key 'type' is document type - 'user', 'event' etc
- sort key is uuid
```

Above idea is almost certainly a poor design. You would end up with a few large partitions, leading to performance problems. Additionally I suggest you would end up making Scans over Queries.

```
- partition key 'id' is just uuid
- sort key is type - 'user', 'event'
```

Above idea is probably a poor design. The sort key gives you no real benefit. Assuming you need to access users, or events etc separately, you will end up performing Scans.

Its highly likely separate tables for users, events etc would be best. The keys within those tables really would just depend on your data. UUIDs may be a good option, but then it depends on how you want to Query data. Date based attributes, especially for events, often make good sort keys.

I suggest you checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48222907/4985580) which is a much longer answer to roughly the same question.

Comment: Thanky you for the reply. I've read your long answer too. Throughput is a tricky thing I wouldn't have noticed at all. I really think 'partition' is a very bad naming for hash key. Having basic understanding now, I'm still not sure how the table should look like if we have related data. For example, we have user and user transactions. Is it a good idea to have key with partition part created from user uuid and sort part created from transaction timestamp (empty for the user)? So user and all transactions for a particular user have the same partition part but different sort part.

Comment: The answer with all such questions will be 'it depends'. It mainly depends on how you want to access your data - that drives your design. If you know what queries you want to do, you can design your schema around that. It also depends to some extent on your priorities - speed, cost, simplicity etc.

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of a subjective question but I'll take a shot and give you some reasons.

1) You can use "uuid:type" as your primary id. The reason you shouldn't use type as the partition id is because all of your data will end up on a single partition for each type. The partitions are how Dynamo and S3 provide parallelization. You would be limiting the ingest and query speeds greatly if you did that.

2) I would personally favor a single table over one per type for pricing reasons. You pay per table read/write capacity. With a single table, you would have less to track and manage. It will be easier to tune the capacity of one table than three.

3) I would not use the sort key in this scenario.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately I haven't got you idea of "uuid:type" partition key. It seems to me there is no any advantage over just using uuid (of course, all uuids are unique for all data).

Comment: Good point about throughput aggregation on a single (or fewer) tables.

Comment: @arsenii fomin. What I meant by "uuid:type" was to use the uuid appended with the type as the partition key. The advantage is that it lets you hold many data types in the same table which I find desirable for the pricing reason I described.

Comment: @jeff I still not very sure what do you mean. If uuid is unique for any object, you still can store different data types in the same table using only it. Anyway the problem here is that usual task is to get all items of some type. Since you don't know uuid and can't query them, you will have to use scan for all such tasks which is very ineffective. Can you provide any ideas how to store several documents types in one table and not to use scan for receiving all docs of the same type?

Comment: Oh. I see. I didn't catch that from your question. You might update the question to reflect that common use case. In that case, I'd likely use different tables. You can store "index records" in your DynamoDB table where partition id is something like "user" with a sort key of "uuid". That would allow you to scan all uuids of users and then do secondary scans for each user record. Though, all the index records would end on a single partition so it likely wouldn't be good if you have millions of records.