# How does DynamoDB partition tables?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

The [DynamoDB documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.Partitions.html) describes how table partitioning works in principle, but its very light on specifics (i.e. numbers). Exactly how, and when, does DynamoDB table partitioning take place?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found this [presentation](https://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/design-patterns-using-amazon-dynamodb) produced by Rick Houlihan (Principal Solutions Architect DynamoDB) from AWS Loft San Franciso on 20th January 2016.

The presention is also on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PDQ3jbDyTQ4&feature=youtu.be).

This slide provides the important detail on how/when table partitioning occurs:

[image]

And below I have generalised the equation you can plug your own values into.

---

*Partitions by capacity* = (**RCUs**/3000) + (**WCUs**/1000)

*Partitions by size* = **TableSizeInGB**/10

*Total Partitions* = Take the largest of your **Partitions by capacity** and **Partitions by size**. Round this up to an integer.

---

In summary a partition can contain a maximum of 3000 RCUs, 1000 WCUs and 10GB of data. Once partitions are created, RCUs, WCUs and data are spread evenly across them.

Note that, to the best of my knowledge, once you have created partitions, lowering RCUs, WCUs and removing data will not result in the removal of partitions. I don't currently have a reference for this.

Answer (score 6):

Regarding the "removal of partitions" point Stu mentioned.

**You don't directly control the number of partitions** and once the partitions are created **they cannot be deleted** => this behaviour can cause **performance issues** which are many times not expected.

Consider you have a Table which has 500WCU assigned. For this example consider you have 15GB of data stored in this Table. This means we reached a data size cap (10GB per partition) thus we currently have **2 partitions between which the RCUs and WCUs are split (each partition can use 250WCU)**.

Soon there will be an enormous increase (let's say Black Friday) of users that needs to write the data to the Table. So what would you do is to increase the WCUs to 10000, to handle the load, right? Well, what happens behind the scenes is that DynamoDB has reached another cap - WCU capacity per partition (max 1000) - so it creates 10 partitions between which the data are spread by the hashing function in our Table.

Once the Black Friday is over - you decide to decrease the WCU back to 500 to save the cost. What will happen is that even though you decreased the WCU, the number of partitions will not decrease => now you have to SPLIT those 500 WCU between 10 partitions (so effectively every partition can only use 50WCU).

You see the problem? This is often forgotten and can bite you if you are not planning properly how the data will be used in your application.

TLDR: **Always understand how your data will be used and plan your database design properly.**

Comment: Is this still an issue, now that DynamDB implements "Adaptive Capacity"?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-design.html#bp-partition-key-partitions-adaptive

Comment: @AntWaters AFAIK the TLDR still applies, though Adaptive Capacity allows to use the provisioned (but not in use) capacity on hot partitions.